# Grouping Key Value pairs with Linq and List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm trying to take a long list of items, a key/value pair, and group them by key. Doing this I want to get the count of each key/value pair so I can for a weighted list later on. The code I have for generating the list is similar to this sample:

```
class Notes
    {
        public int NoteId { get; set; }
        public string NoteName { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Notes> _popularNotes = new List<Notes> { 
              new Notes { NoteId = 1, NoteName = "Title 1" }, 
          new Notes { NoteId = 1, NoteName = "Title 1" },
          new Notes { NoteId = 2, NoteName = "Title 2" },
          new Notes { NoteId = 4, NoteName = "Title 4" },
          new Notes { NoteId = 4, NoteName = "Title 4" } };

            foreach (var _note in _popularNotes)
                Console.WriteLine(_note.NoteId + ": " + _note.NoteName);

            IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, string>> _query = _popularNotes.GroupBy(x => x.NoteId, x => x.NoteName);

            foreach (var _noteGroup in _query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_noteGroup.Key + ": " + _noteGroup.Count());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

This build the list and groups them and I can get the count of each object, I just cant get the value. I can only seem to get just the key.

With I'm sure a million ways to do this I'm really trying to pick one I understand. And well I'm just not understanding it I guess.

So should I go back and get the name from the `_popularNotes` list with a lookup? Or is there another way of actually building and outputting the list with the key/value pair plus the count?

Comment: From a readability standpoint, I would go with the singular Note for your data class name.

Comment: Thanks. I'm always looking to improve readability and have nicer looking names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `_noteGroup.First()`

Answer (score 1):

`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` is an `IEnumerable<TElement>` which means you can enumerate over it.

As per [the documentation of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx):

```
public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>,
    IEnumerable
```

In other words, to spit out the key + count, and then all the elements (names in your case) in that group, you can do:

```
foreach (var _noteGroup in _query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_noteGroup.Key + ": " + _noteGroup.Count());
    foreach (var name in _noteGroup)
        Console.WriteLine("   " + name);
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that I need all three at once to build a single line. SLacks appears to have accomplished this very easily.

Comment: Agreed, if that is what you need, but note that the group is grouped on the NoteId, not the name, meaning that a single group can have many different names, but they all come from nodes with the same id.

Comment: Actually no the note will only ever have one name, and it's associated Id.

Comment: Then why are you grouping on it?

Comment: I really only need to group the Id, but need to include the Name value. The list will contain many of each Id/Name groups just like the sample data shows. Am I coming at this from the wrong angle? The data is essentially just a list of visits to pages. I'm building a listing with the views and names of each page. Think of the main page for SO for pretty much the same thing as I'm doing. Again, maybe it's wrong?